A subset of a CW complex X is closed and discrete if and only if its intersection with each cell is finite
This corresponds to Lemma 5.13 in John Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds-2ed. The proof in the book ends with establishing the fact that if the subset finitely intersects each cell, it has the discrete topology.
My understanding is that a set equipped with the discrete topology is not necessarily a discrete set. Although the proof in the book established that $S\cap\bar{e}$ is finite for each cell $e$, the collection of the cells can be uncountable. I believe if CW complexes are defined by inductively attaching a finite number of higher dimensional cells to the previous complex, the collection of cells would be at most countable, hence S would be at most countable. But Lee made it clear that the book chooses a different definition.
The question is really whether my logical is correct and/or did I miss anything in the book that indicates the collection of cells in the complex is countable?
TLDR: where is the proof that $S$ is a discrete set, despite of the fact that it has the discrete topology?

Lee's definition of a CW complex is standard. There is no restriction concerning the number of cells; there may be uncountably many.
Lee also describes a method to construct CW complexes inductively by attaching cells. Quote from p. 130:

It is possible to define a cell complex as a space formed inductively by starting with a nonempty discrete space $X_0$, attaching some $1$-cells to it to form a space $X_1$, attaching some $2$-cells to that to form a new space $X_2$, and so forth. Many authors do in fact define cell complexes this way, and it is a good way to think about them in order to develop intuition about their properties. However, the theory works more
smoothly if we start out by describing what we mean by a cell decomposition of a given topological space; only later will we come back and describe how to construct cell complexes inductively "from scratch" (see Theorem 5.20).

In Theorem 5.20 there are no restrictions with respect to the number of cells attached at each step.

I believe if CW complexes are defined by inductively attaching a finite number of higher dimensional cells to the previous complex, the collection of cells would be at most countable.

This is correct, but does not contradict Lee's approach. It is just a special case. In this case the set $S$  is in fact at most countable.

My understanding is that a set equipped with the discrete topology is not necessarily a discrete set.

It is unclear what you mean. There is the concept of a discrete space which is a set equipped with the discrete topology. There is nothing like a discrete set without a topology. Sometimes Lee uses the phrase discrete subset, but this applies only to subsets of topological spaces. These receive of course the subspace topology.

Let me trim my question down to one sentence: where is the proof that $S$ is a discrete set, despite of the fact that it has the discrete topology?

@Riemannstein Please explain what precisely you are missing in Lee's proof. If you accept that $S$ has the discrete topology as a subspace, then it is a discrete space.

I accept that it is a discrete space. By Lee's definition (Example 2.1), a discrete space has its powerset as its topology. But it doesn't say anything about the cardinality of the set. By "a subset of X is discrete", I presume it means X is also discrete in the set-theoretical sense. Under that interpretation, my question is again where is the proof that $S$ is a discrete set in the set-theoretical sense? Or maybe there is a different interpretation to "a subset of X is discrete".

@Riemannstein There is no purely set-theoretical concept of a "discrete set" without reference to a topology. Lee considers a subset $S$ of a CW complex $X$, and $S$ receives the subspace topology.

Thanks to your clarification, I see my problem now. By "a pure discrete set" I was really thinking about whether the set is "at most countable" in the set-theoretical sense. But again, you are right that "discrete" has no interpretation in that sense, but only in the sense of the topology. Thank you very much for your answer. The answer is accepted.
